# highstock freezes when adding column

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to plot a stock trend in a highstock chart with volumes as columns in the bottom of the chart.

Everyting works fine as long as I am not adding the columns to the chart. When adding the columns(even without data) the chart freezes.

I have created a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rick822/5fpqfzv4/1/) demonstrating the issue. In the JSfiddle example I have commented out the problematic code:

```
{
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Volume',
    data:  [],
    yAxis: 1
}
```

If I change the 'type' to for example 'spline' everything works:

```
{
    type: 'spline',
    name: 'Volume',
    data:  [],
    yAxis: 1
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem in your fiddle when I uncomment the code. http://jsfiddle.net/5fpqfzv4/2/ I even added data and it seems fine.  What do you mean by "the chart freezes"?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Tried this on my MAC now and it seems to work as you say. However, running it on my windows machine in both chrome and firefox makes the browsers unresponsive and when debugging it is pointing out the row http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.src.js:18455 (approximations.average). Seems like if I wait long enough, like 1 min, it renders fine.

Comment: Well, I run on mac and windows Chrome, in both cases, work well. Check your machine if has addtional plugins or options.